# How to change textcolor of textview in listview depending on it's value?

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, textcolor

I'm having difficulties changing textview's textcolor in my listview.

I have a row that consists of more than one textview but only one textview is visible.

I want the text of that textview to change the color of textview depending on the other textview's value in that row. I'm pretty sure you'll understand what I mean when you see the code.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this, strojeviList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_SIFSTROJA,
                                TAG_NAZIVSTROJA, TAG_AKTIVAN, TAG_AUTH,
                                TAG_IP, TAG_POCETAK},
                        new int[] { R.id.sifstroja, R.id.nazivstroja, R.id.aktivan,
                                R.id.auth, R.id.ip,R.id.pocetak});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
             View v;
            TextView blab= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekst);
           blab.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.zelena));

             ListView lv=getListView();

                TextView akt;
                TextView naziv;
                int bla=lv.getCount();
                Log.d(TAG_AUTH,String.valueOf(bla));
                for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
                    v=(View) lv.getAdapter().getView(i,null,null);
                    akt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.aktivan);
                    naziv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.nazivstroja);
                    String aktiv=akt.getText().toString();
                    String aktivtekst=naziv.getText().toString();

                    Log.d(aktiv, aktiv);
                    if(aktiv.equals("1"))
                    {
                        Log.d("uso","uso sam");
                        Log.d("uso",aktivtekst);

                        naziv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.zelena));

                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("nisam aktivan","nisam aktivan");
                        Log.d("nisam aktivan",aktivtekst);
                        naziv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.crvena));
                    }
                }


            }
```

I can get textview values and if part works just fine but color is not changed, so what can I do to change the color?

Comment: Is this code in a custom adapter?

Comment: no it's outside, I will edit the code in question so you can see it all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move this code inside the adapter's `getView` method, for example:

```
....
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, strojeviList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_SIFSTROJA,
                            TAG_NAZIVSTROJA, TAG_AKTIVAN, TAG_AUTH,
                            TAG_IP, TAG_POCETAK},
                    new int[] { R.id.sifstroja, R.id.nazivstroja, R.id.aktivan,
                            R.id.auth, R.id.ip,R.id.pocetak}){
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView akt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.aktivan);
    TextView naziv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.nazivstroja);
    String aktiv=akt.getText().toString();
    String aktivtekst=naziv.getText().toString();

    Log.d(aktiv, aktiv);
    if(aktiv.equals("1"))
    {
           Log.d("uso","uso sam");
           Log.d("uso",aktivtekst);
           naziv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.zelena));

     }
     else {
           Log.d("nisam aktivan","nisam aktivan");
           Log.d("nisam aktivan",aktivtekst);
            naziv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.crvena));
     }  
    return v;
  }
};
setListAdapter(adapter);

TextView blab= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tekst);
blab.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.zelena));
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, please check my edited code and please explain, I'm sort of new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
naziv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.crvena)));
```

Comment: Do you have hexadecimal code of colors in form of string in the resources?

Comment: yes, I already changed textview color in another activty this way, so that works

Answer (score 0):

There are so many methods to change the `textColor` of `TextView` at runtime:

- `textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));`
- `textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);`
- `textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));`

The thing to notice here is this:

> int **android.graphics.Color.GREEN** = -16711936 **[0xff00ff00]**
>   int **com.example.R.color.green** = 2130968577 **[0x7f040001]**

you can see that both are not same but the **/res/values/color.xml** goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

So I think that because of the difference in both **android.graphics.Color.GREEN** and **com.example.R.color.green** we are not getting the expected results while using `textView.setTextColor(R.color.green);`

Comment: That's not the problem, the color doesn't change at all